# Powermock counts more than actually call when verify

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Is it a bug of Powermock or I'm doing sth wrong?

The following test should pass, but failed with:

```
trackBugPartialMockCountMore(com.xiaomi.finddevice.test.testcase.PowerMockBug)
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
classToMock.foo();
Wanted 1 time:
-> at com.xiaomi.finddevice.test.testcase.PowerMockBug.trackBugPartialMockCountMore(PowerMockBug.java:24)
But was 3 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at com.xiaomi.finddevice.test.testcase.PowerMockBug.trackBugPartialMockCountMore(PowerMockBug.java:22)
```

When I remove @PrepareForTest(ClassToMock.class), every thing goes well and the test get passed.

```
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassToMock.class)
public class PowerMockBug {

    @Test
    public void trackBugPartialMockCountMore() {
        ClassToMock mock = mock(ClassToMock.class);
        when(mock.foo()).thenCallRealMethod();

        mock.foo();

        verify(mock).foo();
    }

}


class ClassToMock {
    public int foo() { return 0x10; }
}
```

VERSION: powermock-mockito-junit-1.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you don't need to use PowerMock because you are not mocking/spying a final or static method. You can safely remove both @RunWith and @PrepareForTest annotations. Only mockito is needed for your purposes